# returned non-zero exit status 120

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, airflow, exit-code

I wrote a piece of code that was supposed to run the `airflow list_dags` command via subprocess.

```
    dags_raw = subprocess.check_output(
        'airflow list_dags', shell=True
    ).split()
```

I get the following error message

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'airflow list_dags' returned non-zero exit status 120.
```

I'm able to run `airflow list_dags` directly from the server. I couldn't find the right solution. I'd appreciate it if anyone could help with this.

```
Apache Airflow [1.10.12]
Platform: [Linux, x86_64]
Python Version: [3.7.3]
```

Comment: You can catch the `CalledProcessError` exception and access the `.output` attribute. It should give you more insights as to what has happened.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this [link](https://bugs.python.org/issue29130#msg284437) could help you.

> Changed in version 3.6: If an error occurs in the cleanup after the Python interpreter has caught SystemExit (such as an error flushing buffered data in the standard streams), the exit status is changed to 120.

Check first if you can invoke `airflow list_dags` with no error in Python using subprocess.

Comment: yes, i did invoke airflow list_dags with no error in Python using subprocess.